# Draw vector field on top of surface of spherical octant, but not in specific regions

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-3d

I am interested in drawing a vector-like field towards, or away from, a single point on the surface of a unit octant. If possible, I would like to constrain this to not occur within an area spanned by some paths. I have the following code in place that produces the image shown below. I furthermore highlighted what I would like.

```tex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{65}{120}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  scale=2.5, tdplot_main_coords,
  Arrow/.style={-{Latex[scale=.7]}},
  ]
  % Draw axes
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (1.2,0,0) node[inner sep=0pt, below left] (r2) {$r_2$};
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1.2,0) node[inner sep=0pt, below right] (r1) {$r_1$};
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1.2) node[inner sep=0pt, above] (r3) {$r_3$};
  % quarter circle on xy plane
  \draw[dashed] (1,0,0) arc (0:90:1); % -- (0,0,0) -- cycle;
  % quarter circle on xz plane
  \tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{0}
  \draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords] (1,0,0) arc (0:90:1); % -- (0,0,0) -- cycle;
  % quarter circle on yz plane
  \tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{90}
  \draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords] (1,0,0) arc (0:90:1); % -- (0,0,0) -- cycle;
  
  \node (A1) at (0.7,0.7,0.1) {};
  \node (A2) at (0.7,0.1,0.7) {};
  \node (A3) at (0.1,0.7,0.7) {}; 
  % Draw triangle on surface with corners A1...A3
  \draw[blue] (A1.center) edge[bend left] (A2.center);
  \draw[blue] (A2.center) edge[bend left] (A3.center);
  \draw[blue] (A3.center) edge[bend left] (A1.center);  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

This is what I currently have.

[image: Current]

---

This is what I'd like.

[image: Arrows in][image: Arrow out]

If possible, I would like to keep it as simple as possible, but I understand that 3D coordinates bring with them some more complicated calculations. If there is also an external library that makes this far easier, I'd be more than happy to learn about it as well.

Comment: I do not fully understand. Do you wish many small arrows(vector field) or just the arrows you have draw. If you only wish the arrows you have drawn, then they automatically(by their position and length) do not lie in the area. Is it needed that the arrows curve following the surface of a sphere? Your area does not.

Comment: It would be nice if I can specify the no. of arrows, but I will not need many as it will be an illustrative picture. Therefore I don't care that much if the arrows follow the surface of the sphere, as long as it looks like it. The same holds for the surface: for its purpose it does not need to follow the surface of the sphere exactly, but if there is a (simple) solution out there in which it does that works as well. 
The only thing that the surface needs to be is (approximately) a triangle on the surface of the sphere.